# Is there a way to convert a html containing chart in javascript to a pdf document using LGPL licenced libraries

Tags: javascript, java, html

Trying to convert a html file containing javascript for rendering chart using certain libraries into a PDF document using HTMLUnit and flying suacer.

The conversion of HTML+JS to PDF is working for certain functions like document.write() , but not working for chart libraries rendering in Javascript

```
URL url = new File("in1.html").toURI().toURL();
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

OutputStream os = null;
os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\cs3339\\Desktop\\latestDoc37.pdf");

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(page, url.toString());
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
```